# How to reverse the color scale in a Plotly Express map?

Tags: python, express, plotly, reverse, colormap

I am trying to draw an animated map using [plotly_express](https://plot.ly/python/plotly-express/).
here is a sample code

```
import plotly.express as px
gapminder = px.data.gapminder()
fig = px.choropleth(gapminder, locations="iso_alpha", 
                    color="lifeExp", hover_name="country", 
                    animation_frame="year", 
                    range_color=[20,80],  
                    color_continuous_scale='RdYlGn')
fig.show()
```

This shows the scale from Red to Green. But I want to reverse it
I want it to start from green to a maximum of red. This is done simply using Matplotlib by adding `'_r'` at the end of the color scale name, i.e., to be `color_continuous_scale='RdYlGn_r'`, but this does not work with plotly_express.
In the [documentation](https://plot.ly/python/colorscales/#predefined-colorscales-in-plotly-express), it is written that we can express the normal color scale in the methods form `color_continuous_scale=px.colors.diverging.RdYlGn`, this works too. However, when I add the .reverse method, i.e. `color_continuous_scale=px.colors.diverging.RdYlGn.reverse` it gives the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-9103eb8a4cd9> in <module>
      5                      range_color=[4, 23],
      6                      title='Fasting durations (h) for the world througout the year',
----> 7                      color_continuous_scale=px.colors.diverging.RdYlGn.reverse)#'RdYlGn')
      8 fig2.show()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\express\_chart_types.py in choropleth(data_frame, lat, lon, locations, locationmode, color, hover_name, hover_data, size, animation_frame, animation_group, category_orders, labels, color_continuous_scale, range_color, color_continuous_midpoint, size_max, projection, scope, center, title, template, width, height)
    822         args=locals(),
    823         constructor=go.Choropleth,
--> 824         trace_patch=dict(locationmode=locationmode),
    825     )
    826 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\express\_core.py in make_figure(args, constructor, trace_patch, layout_patch)
   1007         colorvar = "z" if constructor == go.Histogram2d else "color"
   1008         range_color = args["range_color"] or [None, None]
-> 1009         d = len(args["color_continuous_scale"]) - 1
   1010 
   1011         colorscale_validator = ColorscaleValidator("colorscale", "make_figure")

TypeError: object of type 'builtin_function_or_method' has no len()
```

What is the problem, and how can I override this error and applies the reverse colormap?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The colorscales in `px.colors` are all simple lists, meaning you can use `color_continuous_scale=px.colors.diverging.RdYlGn[::-1]`

(I should add that the reason you're seeing an error like this is that since `px.colors.diverging.RdYlGn` is a list, `px.colors.diverging.RdYlGn.reverse` is defined, so you're currently trying to pass in a function to an argument that expects a string or a list)

Comment: Does `px.colors.diverging.RdYlGn.reverse()` have the same effect as using `[::-1]` ?

Comment: no, because `.reverse()` doesn't return anything, it mutates the list. You can do `list(reversed(px.colors.diverging.RdYlGn))` if you like but this is more verbose. `reversed()` doesn't return a list but an iterator so you need to wrap it :(

Answer (score 6):

Adding `_r` to the palette name now works ([notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1POPpuZxGH5UiJttut9WML2P_f0samoLi?usp=sharing)).

```
import plotly.express as px
gapminder = px.data.gapminder()
fig = px.choropleth(gapminder, locations="iso_alpha", 
                    color="lifeExp", hover_name="country", 
                    animation_frame="year", 
                    range_color=[20,80],  
                    color_continuous_scale='RdYlGn_r')
fig.show()
```

[image]